# Remember the input date in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I am using datepicker. I have  two text fields fromdate and todate. For Example I input month of May when I submit and input a date again the default date should be May also not the current Month.

Here is my code.

```
 $(function() {
    var from = $('#from').val();
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({ dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear:true,
    changeDay:true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    defaultDate:from,
    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "fromDate", selectedDate );
    }

});
```

Comment: hi, take a php variable for date and check if post data exists than put default date  as post data otherwise today date , For this you have to put your code on php page. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, you want to persist the user-selected date between different form submits.

In this case

**HTML Code**

Following is the `input` tag for from date.

```
<input type='text' id='datepicker' name='fromdate' />
```

**PHP View Code**

Let us assume that we have a PHP variable with the name `$fromdate` with the date user submitted. We need to send this from the PHP Controller in CodeIgniter.

I am assuming `$fromdate` is in format : `yyyy-mm-dd`

Based on `$fromdate` this will be the PHP View code.

```
<input 
     type='text' 
     id='datepicker' 
     name='fromdate'
     <?php echo (isset($fromdate)) ? "data-date='" . $fromdate . "'" : ""; ?>
     />
```

**jQuery Code**

Now, if there is any date selected then that date is available on the same control as the attribute `data-date='2013-05-01'`. So, based on that show the default date.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate : new Date($(this).data('date'))
    });
});
```

In the above code, if `$fromdate` is not available, then it will take `new Date()` as the default date, which is today's date.

From your question this is what I understand.

Let me know if you need something else.

Comment: Yes exactly what I need I really like your solutions. Thanks for additional knowledge Vanga.

Answer (score 0):

here is my approach and its working fine i just want to share it

I created a hidden field in html

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $from_h; ?>" id="from_h" />
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $to_h; ?>" id="to_h" />
```

And in my JS file

```
 $(function() {
    var from = $('#from_h').val();
    var to = $('#to_h').val();
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({ dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',defaultDate: from,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear:true,
    changeDay:true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "fromDate", selectedDate );
    }


  });

    $( "#to" ).datepicker({ dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',defaultDate: to,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear:true,
    changeDay:true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
    $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "toDate", selectedDate );
    }


 });    
});
```

And it works !!!

Comment: You can add the `selectedDate` as a `data-` attribute, which will not need any other hidden tags. I tried to add my solution with this. Please check if this explains that.